# Check if product is FBA or FBM

Tags: amazon-mws

Is there any way to check if a product in my Seller Central account is set up for fulfill by Amazon or for fulfill by merchant using the MWS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is the [GetMyPriceForAsin](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMyPriceForASIN.html) operation of the [Products API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Overview.html).  The 
Fulfillment channel in the response will show you either the value of Amazon or Merchant.